# Talmudic Source Mechitzah?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, history, talmud-gemara, mechitza-partition

What's the source in the Talmud for the mechitzah? I have yet to run across it.

Also as an aside, I've been to a lot of Synagogues from Talmudic times, and I have yet to find any mechitzah type of division.

Comment: Did you find much other furniture survived?

Comment: @DoubleAA Benches :D

Comment: @Aaron Maybe the mechitza was a stack of benches?

Comment: @Alex Benches all along the walls, nothing divisive in the center. But the amount of Avodah Zarah imagery on the floors and walls (especially zodiac signs and our Aramaic month names) were scarily prevalent

Comment: How do you know that those shuls had women at all?

Comment: @Orangesandlemons Precisely what I was thinking. Can you be sure women even attended shul at all in Talmudic times? Maybe that was a medieval invention.

Comment: @ezra Yalkut Shimoni Ekev tells of a woman who want to shul every day. Women going to shul isn't a later innovation. (I can't say how popular it was or not.)

Comment: @Shmuel ya because shul wasn't a social scene. It was a Mikdash Me'at and you didn't schmooze in God's presence. JFK (just for Kiddush) meant something different back then: you were homeless.

Answer (score 3):

Rav Moshe in Igros Moshe 1/1/39 writes that it is based on the Gemorah Sukka 51b [Here](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.51b.11-52a.1?lang=bi) that a balcony was made in the Beis HaMikdash in order to separate men and women.

I don't have it in front of me, but at the end of "The Silver Era" about Rabbi Eliezer Silver, there is a transcript of how Rabbi Silver proved the halachic need for a Mechitza in court.